# Hibernate Criteria Query with Predicates to select records from given list of Ids

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I'm trying to write a Hibernate Criteria query with Predicate to fetch records from db from a given list of ids, where id is a column in db table.

What I've done is

```
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

for(String id : ids)
{
    predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get(MyModel.id), Integer.parseInt(id)));
}

//Other predicates I don't care about

Predicate queryPredicate = builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]))

criteriaQuery.select(root);
criteriaQuery.where(queryPredicate);
```

I get 0 result

Answer (score 1):

I think id is unique for each row . you have to use `OR` instaed of `AND`
like

```
Predicate queryPredicate = builder.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]))
```

It is logically false that the records who have all ids.

OR

you have to use `CriteriaBuilder.in()` method for matching the records for exact ids you are giving.